# Stud wall in concrete subfloor and joists

Tags: walls, partition

What considerations are important to take into account when planning a non-load bearing stud / partition wall that will run in parallel to both ceiling and floor joists?

The stud wall will have a sliding door. The length of the wall will be  3m.

The ceiling joists are timber and the floor is concrete.

Can the stud wall be positioned between floor joists and between ceiling joists or does additional support framing need adding.

What framing needs adding in that case. While ceiling can be potentially lifted to install additional blocks between joists, it would be difficult. Is there an alternative?

And what about concrete subfloor? Is there anything required or can the stud wall simply sit in between joists?

Thank you very much in advance for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

The top of the wall needs to be anchored to the joists, or it will just flop around.

You either need to nail the top plate to the ceiling joists or add wood blocks attached to the joists to nail the wall to.

If the cement floor is underground, then recommended to use pressure treated wood on the floor.  Will need to use cement nails/screws to anchor the wall to the floor.

Comment: Construction adhesive might also be a way to anchor the footing to the floor, if you don't want to deal with actual concrete fasteners. Though fasteners are more hassle to install, they're less hassle if you later change your mind. And note that you don't need a _lot_ of fasteners, since this isn't loadbearing and most force from shelves and so forth will be downward; you just don't want it to be able to slide.